# parsing json in perl

Tags: perl, json

i'm trying to parse some json in perl, but am having problems with it. i've read over the docs for it, but still not fully understanding how to code it. i found a few tutorials for it, but still getting errors.  here is the code i have:

```
fetch_json_page("http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&format=json&region=usa&category=sale");

sub fetch_json_page
{
  my ($json_url) = @_;
  my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new();
  eval{
    # download the json page:
    print "Getting json $json_url\n";
    $browser->get( $json_url );
    my $content = $browser->content();
    my $json = new JSON;

    my $json_text = $json->allow_nonref->utf8($content);

    my @decoded_json = decode_json($json_text);
    print Dumper(@decoded_json), length(@decoded_json), "\n";
```

when i run it, i get this error

```
Getting json http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=usa&category=sale
[[JSON ERROR]] JSON parser crashed! malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at ./oodle2.pl line 35.
```

which makes me wonder if i'm getting the data in properly. the url works correctly is pasted into a browser and i've done it fine w/ javascript, but having problems with perl. i added the print Dumper piece to try and print out the json response so i knew if the data was coming in properly

thanks

Comment: Hey, even though there are still TONS of examples using it, don't use indirect object notation.  What this means is, say `my $json = JSON->new;` rather than `my $json = new JSON;`.  There are some potentially hairy bugs related to the later syntax which can be completely avoided by using the other form.  See perldoc perlsub for more info.  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That URL returns XML, not JSON.

**EDIT due to OP updating link**

If you look, that's not a valid JSON object that it's returning thus your parser is failing. The JSON is wrapped by `jsonOodleApi(`*json is here*`);`

If you remove the function call thing, it'll parse.

Comment: i updated the link. i forgot to include format=json. still same error.

Comment: If you look, that's not a valid JSON object that it's returning thus your parser is failing. The JSON is wrapped by `jsonOodleApi();`

Comment: I love APIs that claim to return FOO, but really return something almost like FOO.  Since this string is biggish, for best speed use `substr` to remove the garbage.  `substr $json, 0, 13 = ''; substr $json, -2 = '';`  See `perldoc -f substr` for help with substr.  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html

Answer (score 0):

the page linked you is not json. you cannot reasonably expect a json parser to parse it.

perhaps you would like an xml parser?

Comment: i updated the link. i forgot to include format=json. still same error.